# Protractor - How can I hold es-bdd-id in json file, so I can use it alter in the tests?

Tags: json, protractor

I'm trying to hold data object variables in a json file. Everything works fine with ids, but I can't get it to work for es-bdd-ids. Entry in json file looks like this:

```
   "businessNameInputField":"[es-bdd-id=\"rs-application-business-page-rs-business-form-es-panel-body-es-field-edit-input-businessName\"]"
```

And when I run the script I get error:

```
  WebDriverError: invalid argument: 'value' must be a string
```

How can I keep such variables in a json file? Any help appreciated.

Code:

```
    businessName = getRandomString(9);
    var businessNameInputField = element(by.css(webObjectVariables.businessNameInputField))
    businessNameInputField.sendKeys(businessName)
```

Comment: can you post your code, please?

Comment: still don't get where `'value'` is being used

Comment: Try replacing double quotes with single inside the value - `"[es-bdd-id = \'rs-app... \']"`

Comment: what is the output of `getRandomString(9)` method?